# How can I select all TR elements whose TDs don't contain a table?

Tags: jquery

How can I select:

- all rows in a table (except the first row)
- where each TD in a row does **not** contain a table?

I've tried:

```
var tbl = grd.find("tr:gt(0)").find("tr:not(:has(table)");
```

But this doesn't return any rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you're targeting the rows of the outermost `table` element.

```
$('#mytable > tbody > tr').slice(1)
                          .filter('tr:not(:has(table))');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cvtqM/

---

Or if `grd` is the outer table...

```
grd.children()
   .children()
   .slice(1)
   .filter('tr:not(:has(table))');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grd.find("tr").slice(1).filter( function(){
    return !this.getElementsByTagName("table").length;
});
```

This is pretty reliant on whatever `grd` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector:

```
var tbl = $("tr:not(:has(table)):not(:first)", grd);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHTDq/

This selects rows in the tables that are `<td>` descendants as well, not sure if that's in your requirements or not.